# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: php, windows, apache, google-chrome, openserver

Делаю сайт на PHP, для разработки использую Windows 7 и OpenServer. В какой-то момент я ухожу с работы и на следующее утро я просто не могу ни в какую открыть свой локально развернутый сайт в хроме... Что стряслось за ночь не понимаю, перед уходом все работало.

Пишет:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Веб-сайт использует механизм HSTS. Открыть сайт в настоящее время нельзя.
```

Я никакой HSTS не включал!!! Я даже не знаю что это такое. При этом он все время редиректит на HTTPS, хотя я перехожу по ссылке с HTTP. Что за фигня такая???

Причем в том же Firefox на том же компе открывается все без проблем, значит проблема 100% в браузере, а не в сервере. Кэш чистил, куки чистил, даже комп перезагружал :D - ничего не помогает.

P.S. Гуглил гуглил, в конце концов нашел что-то очень похожее на свою проблему, но пока не знаю как это может помочь. [Ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320164/)

Comment: Это просто ошибка настройки HSTS со стороны сервера. По RFC, загловок HSTS нельзя отдавать в ответ по HTTP, иначе есть шанс поймать кэшированный редирект на нерабочий HTTPS стороне браузера. Проверяйте заголовки, которые ваш сайт отдает с каждым ответом, там скорее всего будет Strict-Transport-Security - и ищите, откуда он берется.

Comment: Собственно, проблема у вас проявляется так: Сайт нарушает [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797), пункт 7.2. HTTP Request Type и отдает хедер Strict-Transport-Security по http. Браузер (хром) нарушает RFC, 8.1. и не игнорирует хедер, переданный по http. В результате вы получаете редирект на нерабочий https. Если браузер игнорирует хедер по http - все работает. Проблема и в бразуере, и в сервере.

Comment: @PashaPash К сожалению это все мне ни о чем не говорит. :( Почему у меня буквально вчера все работало, а на утро уже нет? И что конкретно мне делать/смотреть? Я не силен в настройке апача. Не представляю где там эти заголовки отправляются...

Comment: смотрите заголовки ответа от сервера, ищите в них Strict-Transport-Security

Comment: Также и зона `new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас локальные домены .dev?
Это существующая доменная зона и она принадлежит Google. 
И в последней версии Chrome они по умолчанию включают HSTS для доменов в этой зоне и его нельзя для них отключить

Comment: Да на .dev оканчиваются. Там OpenServer через hosts подменяет адрес чтобы можно было не писать для всех сайтов localhost (это одна из причин за которые я ненавижу пхп :( ) Попробую поменять окончание.

Comment: Поменяйте например на .local - должно решить проблему

Comment: Да, спасибо это помогло! Видимо вечером или за ночь обновился хром...

Comment: мне тоже помогло, все домены были на .dev поменял на .local и заработало

Comment: а что делать тем у кого домен .localhost но проблема таже самая?